# Spring Cloud Gateway - read response body and set response headers

Tags: java, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I want to implement a GatewayFilter that reads the response body and out of this the response code is determined and should then be set afterwards.
I'm aware that this requires buffering as the response headers can only be modified before the body is written.
So far I could not find any solution.
Can somebody please help me or give hints?
Thank you very much.

Comment: yeah, right now the modify response body filter doesn't have access to the ServerWebExchange. I think we need a new filter. Right now you could probably copy and modify https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/rewrite/ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.java

Comment: New filter sounds good, thanks.
With a GlobalFilter I was able to achieve my goal. However this is ugly as I likely do not want to apply this everywhere.